# Dynamic import modules according to environment - AOT

Tags: angular, angular-aot

By following [this article](https://hackernoon.com/conditional-module-imports-in-angular-518294aa4cc) I tried to dynamically import modules to my AppModule according to the environment I'm running (e.g. I only want `StoreDevtoolsModule` in dev, not in production).

My approach was

```
let devImports = [
  StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({maxAge: 25}),
];

if (environment.production) {
  devImports = [];
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    // other imports
    ...devImports,
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

And it worked when running `ng s`, but then I tried running with AOT to check if it works as well with
`node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng s --aot`
and it didn't, `StoreDevtoolsModule` was imported and I was able to use the extension to see my app state.

I can understand why AOT fails to dynamically import modules, but **is there another way**? I have [this article](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2017/07/23/environment-specific-modules-services-and-components-in-angular/) with different approach to try yet, but I don't know if it works for that compilation approach.

(I know I can `logOnly: environment.production` for `StoreDevtoolsModule`, it was just an example)

Thanks.

Comment: while there are other problems, `instrument` isn't going to work because angular can't turn it into json metadata. The reason it doesn't work with AOT is because in AOT decorators aren't decorators at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I get why it won't work with AOT and it was just an example to use StoreDevtoolsModule, but, does it implies that other modules that you call a method inside, like `StoreModule.forRoot(reducer)` won't work with dynamic import for AOT? Is there a way to dynamic import them, as asked? Thanks again.